# After adding splashscreen to my app, app has a white border when screen is rotated

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

After adding the following to `themes.xml` :

```xml
  <style name="Theme.App" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar"/>

    <style name="Theme.App.starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen.IconBackground">

        <item name="windowSplashScreenIconBackgroundColor">@color/App_launcher_background</item>

        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/black</item>

        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/App_launcher_foreground</item>

        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.App</item>

    </style>
```

And using it with `installSplashScreen()` in the main activity, the app has now a white border when rotating the screen :

[image: App with white border]

It wasn't the case when using `Theme.App` :

[image: App with proper rounded border and black color]

It's a Jetpack Compose App with theme defined in Theme.kt.

Any idea how to solve this issue ?

Thank you

EDIT : As a workaround, I added `enableEdgeToEdge()` before `setContent`. Of course, only a workaround, explanation still needed.